# How to handle JSON-LD with @ in it

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have the following JSON-LD document, fully valid in ie https://json-ld.org/playground/:

https://gist.github.com/viggis75/27129127a1d3bd84b04f8af4f8e83ff4

I'm trying to use JsonPath to fetch nodes fromo this document, but I'm struggeling when I want to make a filter with Predicates which match on fields with @ in it.

The JSON-LD document linked to above has two orders, but ideally I would like to for example to get all orders where the orderDelivery.provider.employee[@id] is a given id that I provide as input.

or, I would like to get all orders where the orderDelivery[@type] is "ParcelDelivery" or something else I provide as input to the filter.

The code I've written so far looks like this:
    JsonArray getOrdersByFoo(String orderDeliveryType) throws NoOrdersForDriverFoundException {
        InputStream ordersAsStream = null; // this is where I read the JSON-LD document into

```
    Filter ordersByOrderDeliveryTypeFilter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where("orderDelivery[@type]").eq(orderDeliveryType));
    List<Map<String, Object>> orders = JsonPath.parse(ordersAsStream).read("$[*][?]", ordersByOrderDeliveryTypeFilter);
    if(orders == null || orders.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoOrdersForDriverFoundException();
    }
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(ordersAsStream);   
    JsonArray ordersAsJsonArray = jsonReader.readArray();        

    return ordersAsJsonArray;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Filter ordersByOrderDeliveryTypeFilter = Filter.filter(Criteria.where("orderDelivery['@type']").eq(orderDeliveryType));
List<Map<String, Object>> orders = JsonPath.parse(ordersAsStream).read("$[*][?]", ordersByOrderDeliveryTypeFilter);
if(orders == null || orders.isEmpty()) {
    throw new NoOrdersForDriverFoundException();
}
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(ordersAsStream);   
JsonArray ordersAsJsonArray = jsonReader.readArray();        

return ordersAsJsonArray;
```

}